# The page isn't redirecting properly while redirecting to custom error page

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, smtpclient

while entering any page which is not exist. its giving error - The    page isn't redirecting properly .its not redirecting to    HttperrorPage.aspx

is this code correct ? will it go custom error page or it will send mail.

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();
    if (ex.GetType() == typeof(HttpException))
    {
        if (ex.Message.Contains("NoCatch") || ex.Message.Contains("maxUrlLength"))
            return;

        Response.Redirect("HttpErrorPage.aspx");

    }
    Response.Write("<h1 style='text-align:center'>Sorry There is Some Technical Problems Occured.Try again Later </h2>\n");
    Response.Write("<h1 style='text-align:center'>We Will get back to u shortly</h2>\n");
    EmailTheException(ex);
    Server.ClearError();
}
private void EmailTheException(Exception ex)
{
    System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
    mail.To.Add(new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("krishnamohan.p@sun.com"));
    mail.Subject = "An Application Exception has Occurred.";
    mail.Body = ex.ToString();

    System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient MailServer = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
    try
    {
       // MailServer.Send(mail);
    }
    catch (System.Net.Mail.SmtpException smtpEx)
    {
        //write logging code here and capture smtpEx.Message
    }
}
```

Comment: Recommending reading up on .NET code standards as well.

Answer (score 0):

Will relative path works? Response.Redirect("~/HttpErrorPage.aspx");

Comment: no that also not working.and giving error saying-"The page isn't redirecting properly"@stevanuz

Comment: looks like there is an infinite redirection then. does the HttpErrorPage.aspx throw an exception too in your code?

Comment: yes how to stop infinite redirection. and i got 88 mails at once@stevanuz

Comment: firstly close your browser first if it's still running now ^^

Comment: am not that sure, but if the redirection indeed works then there must be an exception that causes the redirection again and again. If you have fiddler, just open it and inspect if it redirects to HttpErrorPage.aspx just to make sure that it redirects to the right page. Do you have any httpmodule that may throw the exception probably if not in the page?